# How to make a page that can't be scrolled?

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is supposed to be on a mobile browser, such as iPad or Android tablet in school or offices. On this website, you choose emojis according to your mood. I want to make the website to be solid so that when people miss click the emoji the page won't scroll up or down.

Comment: overflow: hidden; in css on the body ?

Comment: use `position: fixed`

Comment: @JamesCoyle I believe not, because that question specifically asks for answers not using `position: fixed;`, which I believe is the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your CSS file such a code :

```
body{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **overflow: hidden** on the body to disable the scroll possibility.

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden
  }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Lectus sit amet est placerat. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. A cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis.

Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum.

Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent.

Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a. Pretium lectus quam id leo. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla.

Neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Sed enim ut sem viverra. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget. Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Leo duis ut diam quam. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Cras sed felis eget velit aliquet. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a containing div that wraps the emoji selector then you could do the following:

```
html { position: relative; }
div.container { position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to style `position: fixed;` on the `<body>`, which will disable scrolling. Then you can add the below CSS to also remove padding/margin and lock the body in the correct place.

```css
html, body {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ullamcorper mattis ultricies. Aenean sollicitudin orci sit amet mi tristique, sed fringilla mi semper. Nullam massa tellus, convallis ac est et, scelerisque accumsan orci. Nulla in convallis dolor. Donec a tempus justo. Etiam iaculis varius metus auctor sodales. Pellentesque consectetur vulputate eleifend. Aenean quis nibh eu enim interdum lobortis ut quis nunc. Etiam mattis consequat metus ut venenatis. Maecenas ac massa nec mi elementum bibendum. Nam finibus pellentesque sem, vestibulum tincidunt est ultrices quis.

Aliquam luctus ante elit, et laoreet nunc fringilla id. Duis condimentum eget velit eu bibendum. In at massa dolor. Aliquam accumsan eu turpis et pharetra. Aenean lobortis massa eu lectus egestas pharetra ut in dolor. Morbi libero ligula, dictum nec leo nec, consequat efficitur augue. Curabitur sed semper dolor, ut ultrices nisi. Proin vulputate libero a libero malesuada posuere. Etiam porttitor est quis vestibulum ornare. Ut cursus, diam ut mattis sagittis, ligula tortor blandit lacus, in rutrum odio odio sed massa. Praesent ultrices non metus vel elementum.

Suspendisse semper quis turpis non tempus. Duis non auctor ex. Vivamus ipsum ligula, rhoncus nec venenatis sit amet, blandit ut diam. Morbi in dolor enim. Fusce vitae diam ut ante semper luctus. Vestibulum et finibus nulla. Quisque nec metus ultrices, condimentum ex ut, interdum ligula. Quisque tempor interdum urna, at rutrum tellus bibendum vel. Sed at mauris cursus, fringilla metus vitae, faucibus enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Duis suscipit malesuada lectus, bibendum vulputate enim tincidunt eu. Aliquam sodales, sapien a tempus ornare, urna erat rutrum nibh, a viverra elit metus quis felis. Donec lobortis purus ut nisl elementum egestas. Sed sit amet diam id felis aliquet vulputate vel non lorem. Aliquam ac scelerisque quam. Cras quis sem vehicula, rhoncus ante vitae, tincidunt ante. Suspendisse quis sapien eget magna fringilla eleifend. In vulputate nisl arcu, elementum semper lorem scelerisque eget. Mauris justo felis, dapibus non luctus sit amet, convallis sollicitudin dui. Pellentesque lorem odio, fermentum eget accumsan eget, dignissim quis mi. Pellentesque dolor est, placerat sagittis nibh at, dictum condimentum diam. Cras non nulla egestas augue malesuada convallis. Suspendisse commodo erat et urna porta condimentum. Ut at diam ut mi vulputate ullamcorper.
```